# static List lazy initialization fail

Tags: android, static, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that get its adapter from a List. I get the List from a static method :

```
private static List<VerticalPagerAdapter> verticalAdapters;
public static List<VerticalPagerAdapter> getVerticalPagerAdapterList(FragmentManager fm) {
//        List<VerticalPagerAdapter> verticalAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
    if (verticalAdapters==null) {
        verticalAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
        GraphModel graphModel = GraphModel.getInstance();
        int numberOfYears = graphModel.getLastYear()-graphModel.getFirstYear();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++) {
            verticalAdapters.add(new VerticalPagerAdapter(fm, i, 2, DoubleVPChildFragment.class));
        }
    }
    return verticalAdapters;
}
```

If I create a new array by uncommenting the line 3 and commenting the condition, everything works fine, but this is a test code sample and the creation of the array may become CPU intensive in some cases.

So I tried to lazy initialize the ArrayList, but it doesn't work : only the second fragment is populated (not the first one, strange isn't it ?).

This is part of my testing of [my library](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/DoubleFragmentViewpager), so you can try [the sample project](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/DoubleFragmentViewpager/tree/master/DoubleViewpagerSample/src/main/java/fr/chaltiel/doubleviewpagersample) (only 2 classes) to see my problem.

Comment: What exactly are you getting when you use this in the first fragment?

Comment: I have a normal horizontal viewpager that holds custom vertical viewpagers. I have to get the list of verticalviewpagersadapters inside my parent fragment, and I choose the right adapter upon the horizontal position. Since I get it from a fragment, I need it static. I'm not sure I'm clear, but I don't really know how to explain it better.

Comment: It sounds like there is just a problem with the rendering of the list in your first fragment.  Use a debugger to find out if the object being returned from getVerticalPagerAdapterList is the thing you're expecting.

Comment: I get a plain old good list, and even the size is OK, but still it's not working and I don't know how to find out why.

Comment: So I think it's probably not the code that you're showing here, but whatever other code in the fragment that's making use of the list built here.

Comment: No, since it works without lazy initialization, I think the problem comes from it, no ?

Comment: I just don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107789/discussion-between-dan-chaltiel-and-doug-stevenson).